# How to use @Timed of Micrometer to capture metrics for Future

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, spring-micrometer

I'd like to use Micrometer to record the execution time, exception type (If any) of an async method when it eventually happens. Is there a recommended way to do this?

For example aws sqs provide sqsasync client I want the micrometer to listen to Future returned by it and expose success and failure latency metrics

```
@Timed(value = PrometheusConstants.SQS_ASYNC_PUBLISH_TIMER, percentiles = {0.5, 0.95, 0.99}, histogram = true)
public Future<SendMessageResult> sendAsync(String queueUrl, String message) {
        return amazonSQSAsync.sendMessageAsync(queueUrl, message);
    }
```

The above example is not working even though my localstack sqs is down Micrometer is treating the requests as a success.

Note: the example is supposed to work based on documentation but it is not working https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_the_timed_annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [measureTimeMillis](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-time-millis.html) to measure the time of your async function and then use [Timer.builder](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.4/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Timer.Builder.html) to create your timer and the [record](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_recording_blocks_of_code) method to record your metric.

```
//create your Meter registry
MeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();

// create your timer
val myTimer = Timer.builder("my.timer")
.publishPercentileHistogram()
.register(registry);

// Executes the given block and returns elapsed time in milliseconds
val asyncFunctionTime = measureTimeMillis {
    sendAsync()    
}

// Record the metric and send to micrometer
myTimer.record(asyncFunctionTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

For more information you can take a look on the Micrometer [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts)